# Problema com Slide - Navegador Firefox

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Estou com um problema de desenvolvimento CSS de um Slide, somente no navegador Firefox. 
Para o site estou usando um plugin de slide [Jquery Malsup](http://jquery.malsup.com/)

O Slide funciona perfeitamente em outros navegadores,  menos no modo Desktop do Firefox.. (Versão 54.0.1)
Vejam as imagens.

[image: Imagem Tela - 1]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A Pagina inicial fica vazia, mas se rolar a pagina para direita a imagem foi para lá.. 
já adicione `margin-left 0. left:0` e não resolve, só ajusta se eu mudar a propriedade `Inline-Block` para `block`, mas ai eu acabo tendo problema com as transições do slide que ficam estranhas, abaixo meu código. Dicas?

HTML / PHP

```
  <!--                          Slide                            -->

            <!-- Bloco do Slide e configs de tipo e botão --> 
           <div class= "cycle-slideshow"

                data-cycle-caption-plugin="caption2"           
                data-cycle-timeout="3500"
                Data-cycle-auto-height="container"   
                data-cycle-pager=".cycle-pager"           
                >             


                <?php  


                // repassando os parametros para a consulta e armazenando na variavel $result
                $result = $objeto->SlideConsulta();

                // percorrendo o array através de um laço para exibir as imagens
                foreach($result as $dados){

                $linkslide = $dados->caminhourl;
                ?>     

               <img src="<?=$dados->caminho?>" alt="<?=$dados->descricao?>" data-cycle-desc="<?=$dados->descricao?>" onclick="clickslide('<?=$linkslide?>')">

                <?php
                // fim foreach
                }    

                ?>              
            </div>      
            <div class=cycle-pager></div>
```

CSS

```
  /***************************** SLIDESHOW **********************************************/

    .cycle-slideshow {   
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: -325px;
        left: 0px;      
        /* exibindo a mão (no mouse) ao passar em cima da imagem */
        cursor: pointer;

    } 

    /* pager */
    .cycle-pager { 
        text-align: center; 
        width: 100%; 
        z-index: 500; 
        position: absolute; 
        margin-top: -100px; 
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .cycle-pager span { 
        font-family: arial; 
        font-size: 80px; 
        width: 33px; 
        height: 16px; 
        display: inline-block; color: #ddd; cursor: pointer; 
    }
    .cycle-pager span.cycle-pager-active { 
        color: #cc6666;
    }
    .cycle-pager > * { cursor: pointer;}

    /* IMAGEM */
    .cycle-slideshow img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .cycle-caption {
        top: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        color: white;
        bottom: 15px;
        right: 15px;
        z-index: 700;
    }

    /* overlay * Caption  Slide */
    .cycle-overlay {
        position: absolute;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        color: #fff;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 600;
        color: white;
        font-size: 2rem;
        padding: .6rem;
    }
```

Comment: Qual é a versão do seu plugin? Cycle2?

Comment: Sim! cycle 2! abraços!

Comment: Talvez possa ser conflito do seu CSS. Mova o CSS do *slideshow* para o último da lista de arquivos em `head`.

Comment: não estou usando um css externo.. o codigo do css que postei acima está dentro da minha folha de estilo personalizada.... abraços

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para quem estiver com o mesmo problema,basta não utilizar o complemento do plugin

```
data-cycle-auto-height=container
```

Esse complemento aparentemente tem um bug somente em navegadores firefox. Deixei de usar ele e chamei a div conforme abaixo e aí o problema foi resolvido!

```
  <div class="cycle-slideshow"                
            data-cycle-caption-plugin="caption2"
            data-cycle-speed="800"
            data-cycle-timeout="3000"
            data-cycle-manualSpeed="800"
            data-cycle-prev="#anterior"
            data-cycle-next="#proximo"
            >
```